# Prove if $n^3$ is odd, then $n^2 +1$ is even

Tags: logic

I'm studying for finals and reviewing this question on my midterm. My question is stated above and I can't quite figure out the proof.

On my midterm I used proof by contraposition by stating:
If $n^2 +1$ is odd then $n^3$ is even.

I let $n^2+1 = (2m+1)^2 + 1$

$= (4m^2 + 4m + 1) + 1$

$= 2(2m^2 + 2m + .5) + 1$

Let $2m^2 + 2m + .5 = k$

$n^2 + 1 => 2k + 1$

Therefore proving that $n^2 + 1$ was odd making $n^3$ even.

I know my logic was messed up somewhere..some guidance would be nice.

Comment: If $n^2 + 1$ is odd, then $n^2 + 1 = 2m + 1$, not $n$. $n$ could very well be even: for example, $2^2 + 1 = 5$ is odd, but $2$ is even.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but you made a *lot* of errors in your proof. It may be in your best interest  to review the material / talk to your teacher so you can get a true understanding and feel for the material. For example, in your proof by contraposition you want to assume that $n^2 + 1$ is odd and show that that implies that $n^3$ is even, but instead you used that to assume that $n$ is odd and falsely showed that that implied that $n^2 + 1$ is odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n^2+1$ is odd then $n^2+1 = 2m+1 \longrightarrow n^2 = 2m \longrightarrow n^3 = 2mn \longrightarrow n^3=2(mn)$ so that $n^3$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

You assumed $n$ is odd and proved $n^2+1$ is odd (which is false).  You need to assume $n^2+1$ is odd and show that $n^3$ is even.

An alternate root might be easier:  If $n^3$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.  Use that to show that $n^2+1$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ and $n^3=8k$, and we have that $n^3$ is even.So, if $n^3$ is 
odd then $n$ is odd, otherwise  if $n$ is even, by the previous statement we would have $n^3$ even given a contradiction. So, $n$ is odd, and then $n=2t+1$ so $n^2+1=(2t+1)^2+1=
4t^2+2t+1+1=2(2t^2+t+1)$ then, $n^2+1$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the original assumption you made in your proof was incorrect. Rather than letting $n^2 + 1 = (2m + 1)^2 + 1$ (i.e., $n = 2m + 1$), you should let $n^2 + 1 = 2m + 1$. Rustyn shows how to continue with this implication. However, I'll give a different method of proof, using modular arithmetic.

> Suppose $n^3$ is odd. Then $n^3\equiv 1\pmod 2$. However, if we compute the two cubes mod $2$, we have $0^3\equiv 0$ and $1^3\equiv 1$, so that $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$. Hence, $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ n^2\!+\!1\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\, n^2$ even $\,\Rightarrow\, n^3$ even, $ $ i.e. $\,2\mid \color{#c00}{n^2}\,\Rightarrow\, 2\mid n \color{#c00}{n^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved with the knowledge that an odd number times an odd number is still and odd number? From here, it's easy to get $n$ is odd, $n^2$ is odd, $n^2 + 1$ is eve.

Answer (score 0):

If $n^3$ is odd, then $n^3-1$ is even. Now, $n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$, since that one of $(n-1)$, $(n^2+n+1)$ (or both) must be even. 
'
Suppose that $n-1$ is even, then $n$ is odd, $n^2$ is odd and $n^2+1$ is even.

If $n-1$ is odd, then $n$ is even and $n^2+1$ is also odd. Therefore, $n-1$ must be even.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{even}[1]{#1\text{ is even}}
$Many answers already, but I would write down the solution for this yet differently, using the rules
\begin{eqnarray}
\tag{0} \even{k + m} \;\equiv\; \even k \equiv \even m \\
\tag{1} \even{k \times m} \;\equiv\; \even k \lor \even m \\
\end{eqnarray}

Obviously I'm writing this down in a lot of detail for this question.

We start with the most complex side, and calculate
\begin{align}
& \even{n^2 + 1} \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"using $(0)$ and the fact that 1 is not even"} \\
& \lnot(\even{n^2}) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"write $\;n^2\;$ as $\;n \times n\;$; rule $(1)$"} \\
& \lnot(\even n \lor \even n) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: add one more $\;\even n\;$ -- so that we can introduce $\;n^3\;$"} \\
& \lnot(\even n \lor \even n \lor \even n) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"rule $(1)$, twice; write $\;n \times n \times n\;$ as $\;n^3\;$"} \\
& \lnot(\even{n^3}) \\
\end{align}

This proves the required statement.  (It actually also proves the other direction.)